# Why select on change method doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to call a function when a value from the select box is chosen. I would also have a default value selected and a button appear for that value on the page.

This is my select box:

```
<select id="messagingMode" class="bootstrap-select" >
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Webhooks messaging</option>
    <option value="2">Real time messaging</option>
</select>
```

This is the js:

```
$('#messagingMode').on('change',showCorrespondingAuthorizationBtn(this));
```

And the function just prints the selected value for the moment:

```
function showCorrespondingAuthorizationBtn(select) {
    console.log(select.val());
}
```

Nothing is printed in the console, why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 3):

Try with direct call `function name` not with `function()` .Default bind with `this` in change function

```js
$('#messagingMode').on('change',showCorrespondingAuthorizationBtn);

function showCorrespondingAuthorizationBtn() {
    console.log($(this).val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="messagingMode" class="bootstrap-select">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Webhooks messaging</option>
    <option value="2">Real time messaging</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are invoking the function, not passing it as reference. Also `this` is not what you think it is in that context.

Try:

```
$('#messagingMode').on('change',showCorrespondingAuthorizationBtn);

function showCorrespondingAuthorizationBtn(event) {
  console.log($(this).val());
  // or
  console.log(this.value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery event delegation:

```
 $('#messagingMode').on('change',function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
 });
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/dth7g0bh/) is a working fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

$('#messagingMode').change(function () {

showCorrespondingAuthorizationBtn($(this).val());

});

Answer (score 0):

It is not triggering because your are invoking the method on your event attachment logic.

```
 // calling the invocation operator () triggers the method
 $('#messagingMode').on('change',showCorrespondingAuthorizationBtn(this));
```

In order to solve this, try the following code.

```
function onDropdownChanged() {
  var sender = $(this); 
  console.log(sender.val());
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#messagingMode').on("change", onDropdownChanged);
})
```